# -SQL - Get date up to present date and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to get the date from the start up to present date and year.

For example:

`Date Today Jan 31 , 2020`

the result must be

> jan 1 - 31 2020 ,

Another example: if the date is `june 30, 2020`
the result must be

> jan 1 - june 30, 2020

Can you help me how to do it ? , i'm planning to use BETWEEN

Comment: *"i'm trying to get the date"* a **string** like `'jan 1 - 31 2020'` and `'jan 1 - june 30, 2020'` aren't a `date`. What you are after here is pretty unclear too. Explain your logic. What does `BETWEEN` have to do with this? What have *you* tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @date date = ' 2019-05-01'

SELECT EOMONTH(@date), DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, @date), 0)
```